# How to know whether the whole unpeeled garlic is still edible or not?

Tags: garlic

My whole unpeeled garlic has turned "very soft". Its internal texture has changed too.

What are the indicators of non-edible whole garlic?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are three signs you want to look for on garlic that indicate you may not want to use it:

1. Signs of mold, especially black mold.  Discard the garlic.
2. Soft to finger pressure.  It is rotten.  Discard.
3. Sprouted.  While it is still safe to eat (if it doesn't have other issues), it may be bitter.

Good garlic should be quite hard when pressed with your fingers, and preferably is not sprouted.  Some people even remove the green core of partially or beginning to sprout garlic when they prep.

Comment: Firmness is my go to measure for garlic quality, especially at the market. I only buy rock hard garlic!

Comment: Is there a source which says that if the garlic is soft then it is rotten?